# Add quotes in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure whereby text is the input. Is it possible to accept text without quotes and then through the replace function insert single quotes inside the procedure?

Comment: your question is not very clear, please provide examples

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL's [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function:

> Quotes a string to produce a result that can be used as a properly escaped data value in an SQL statement. The string is returned enclosed by single quotation marks and with each instance of backslash (“`\`”), single quote (“`'`”), ASCII `NUL`, and Control+Z preceded by a backslash. If the argument is `NULL`, the return value is the word “NULL” without enclosing single quotation marks.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT QUOTE('Don\'t!');
>         -> 'Don\'t!'
> mysql> SELECT QUOTE(NULL);
>         -> NULL
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where and how to put back the quotes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want to be able to write, for example:

```
foo(All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.)
```

and have it be interpreted as:

```
foo('All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.')
```

then — no. This is not possible.

Comment: @eggyal: "Can I get my Model T in red?" "Yes, of course, as long as by 'red' you mean 'black'."